# Add to DATE hour - TSQL

Tags: date, t-sql, time, format

I have a column type `time(7)`.

What i want is to add in time column to date.

i manage to get the only date using `GETDATE()` function but i fail to add the time part next to date.

**Query:**

```
SELECT [Compay]
      ,[Time]
      ,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS Today
      ,CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR) AS Today_AS_Nvarchar
      ,CAST([Time] AS NVARCHAR) AS Time_AS_Nvarchar
      ,CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST([Time] AS NVARCHAR) AS Today_Time_AS_Nvarchar
      ,CONVERT(datetime,CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST([Time] AS NVARCHAR),103)
  FROM [Testing_Env].[dbo].[Com_CD_Test]
```

**Error:**

`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

The error arise on `CONVERT(datetime,CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST([Time] AS NVARCHAR),103)`

is there any easier/orthodox way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add the new date and time data types together like you can the old data types; personally I think this is also better as it stop people treating dates and times like a numerical value.

*Assuming* you have a `date` column and a `time` column you have a few of options. The first is to `CAST`/`CONVERT` both to a `datetime` and then "add" them together. Because the "old" data types work more like numerical values this works, however, you will lose accuracy of your `time` value if it has a precision of `3` or higher (as `datetime` is only accurate to 1/300 seconds):

```sql
DECLARE @TimeValue time(7) = '17:52:12.1234567',
        @DateValue date = '20211016';
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @DateValue) + CONVERT(datetime, @TimeValue);
```

If loosing accuracy isn't an option, then you *could* to use conversion on the `date` value and use `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD`. For a `time(7)` you'll want to be using nanoseconds (as microseconds isn't accurate enough). Unfortunately this poses another problem; `DATEADD` can't handle `bigint` values (still) and there is no `DATEADD_BIG` (like there is `DATEDIFF_BIG`), so this becomes overly complex. You need to first get the difference in milliseconds, and then add the remainder in nanoseconds to still be accurate to 1/1000000 of a second:

```sql
DECLARE @TimeValue time(7) = '17:52:12.1234567',
        @DateValue date = '20211016';
SELECT DATEADD(NANOSECOND,DATEDIFF_BIG(NANOSECOND,'00:00:00', @TimeValue) % 1000000,DATEADD(MILLISECOND, DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND,'00:00:00', @TimeValue), CONVERT(datetime2(7),@DateValue)));
```

Finally, yes, you can convert to values to strings, and then to a `datetime2` value; this is probably the easiest methiod. You just need to ensure you use style codes:

```sql
DECLARE @TimeValue time(7) = '17:52:12.1234567',
        @DateValue date = '20211016';
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(7),CONVERT(varchar(10), @DateValue, 23) + 'T' + CONVERT(varchar(17), @TimeValue, 114),126);
```